# How to concatenate variables in javascript embedded in php?

Tags: javascript, php

I'm using the following code but it is not concatenating the "show" and X although X is defined as var X=1.

```
echo"  <li class=\"\" id=\"frame\"
onClick=\"ballFunctions[\"show\"+X]();\"><a href=\"#\"> <b> $value</b>
</a> </li> <script type=\"text/javascript\"> X++; </script>  ";
```

Is there any syntax problem?

Comment: What does it output as? The quotes on `ballFunctions[` I think would be closing the attribute. Use single quotes for the JS values.

Comment: it outputs nothin and when I check the source it has ["show"+x] as same

Comment: `it outputs nothin` and `when I check the source it has` are contradictory statements. Are there errors in the console?

Comment: Actually I'm using this code to change the function names. That thing is not happening.

Comment: If you're defining X as a JS variable then all of those onclick handlers will refer to the same X, and by the time a link is clicked X will be 1 greater than the number of li elements.

Comment: WHAT if I want to increase the value of X not by clicking but after execution of php code?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if your code is correct, but here is the code:

```
echo '  <li class="" id="frame"
onClick="ballFunctions[\'show\'+X]();"><a href="#"> <b> '.$value.'</b>
</a> </li> <script type="text/javascript"> X++; </script>  ";
```

Here `X` seems to be a JS variable...

Answer (score 0):

Generally, it's better to avoid mixing PHP and js as much as you can, and/or try to group it as much as you can. Where it's unavoidable, I use single quotes to concat js and double quotes for PHP.

It looks like your code might be echoing out of a loop in PHP, is that correct? If so, you could just increment X with PHP instead,...would be faster, simpler, more readable and you wouldn't need to concat js at all.

```
echo "<li class=\"\" id=\"frame\" onClick=\"ballFunctions['show".$X."']();\"><a href=\"#\"><b>".$value."</b></a></li>";
$X++;
```

Comment: I need to concat because I want to make different JS functions name.  And you are right about php loop :)

Comment: PHP parses first, as far as js is concerned, the PHP is just HTML. But, you're opening and closing <script> blocks for each iteration which has performance consequences and is a bad habit.

I added the code to my answer.